# ios - Launch Apple Mail Exchange App from within my own App?

Tags: ios, swift, email, url-scheme, apple-mail

I am trying to launch the exchange mail app configured via apple mail on an ios app written in react-native. I know that we can use the `mailto` and `message` urlschemes to open the mail app, but none of these target a specific mail app installed via apple mail.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH4-SW1

The above opens the default mail app selected in apple mail. Is there a way to that to a targetted mail app?

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Does the other app provide its own custom URL scheme? If so, use that. If not, you can't.

Comment: No, its doesnt. But I can get that set up, but how will that help me select a detected mail within apple mail?